# Tipo de dato en MySQL equivalente a Datos adjuntos en Access 2016

Tags: mysql, ms-access, conversión-de-tipos

En la tabla Factura (Invoice en inglés) hay un campo llamado Documentación (InvoiceAttach en inglés) con tipo de dato MEDIUMBLOB

[image: Campo InvoiceAttach en MySQL Workbench]

Aún así, cuando hago una conexión ODBC en Access 2016, me lo visualiza como Objeto OLE, y necesito que este campo sea de Datos Adjuntos.

[image: Vista diseño tabla invoice]

Cuál es el tipo de dato MySQL equivalente a Datos Adjuntos MySQL, para que en el formulario salte la acción de "Examinar" y subir el archivo en Windows? En un OLE solamente te permite hacer con clic derecho insertar un objeto o crear uno nuevo; esto es, en la tercera imagen a continuación aparece "Examinar", pero es un poco engorroso para el usuario final.

[image: Inserción objeto OLE en formulario (1)]

[image: Inserción objeto OLE en formulario (2)]

[image: Inserción objeto OLE en formulario (3)]

Muchas gracias por la ayuda :)

Comment: Tu pregunta no es clara. Pulsa en [edit] para completarla. Explica por ejemplo qué estás haciendo concretamente y dónde aparece el problema. Por ejemplo: ¿estás migrando datos de un lado a otro, de qué modo?

Comment: un blob no sirvio por algo en particular? pero de que formulario hablas donde queres que salga examinar? tene en cuenta que access es una base de datos "rara".. o sea es una base de datos y a la vez un programa.... hay un monton de cosas raras que hace access, que una base de datos no va a hacer

Comment: @gbianchi Lo sé, compañero. Aún así, uno de los requisitos para este Front-End es tener este campo como tipo Datos Adjuntos, integrado con vinculación a MySQL

Comment: Entonces guarda los datos en um blob (aunque yo no lo recomiendo)... y eso que te permite subir el archivo es una funcionalida de access.. vas a tener que replicarla en tu front end...

Comment: @gbianchi Entiendo. Y si deseas visualizar ese blob, sea documento o foto, cómo se haría en este caso con tablas vinculadas con ODBC? Muchas gracias.

Comment: No lo se... un blob son datos binarios... para la base de datos no es nada. Ya te dije, access es un caso especial.. para una base de datos normal, vos tenes que leer y mostrar eso sabiendo lo que es

Comment: @gbianchi Ya veo, muchas gracias por la explicación.

Comment: A mi me parece bastante clara. Mas que nada porque yo me encuentro con el mismo problema. Teniendo el backend en access es mas sencillo, porque en la tabla puedes ponerlo el campo como datos adjuntos, esto te permite ir añadiendo documentos, imágenes, etc... en el mismo campo. Pero el problema es cuando el backend lo tienes en SQL, siguiendo un consejo lo declaré en la SQL como campo "varbinary(MAX) pero al actualizarlo en el Front-end te lo declara como Objeto OLE, no como datos adjuntos. Solo te per mite copiar una cosa, no varias.

Comment: @DavElsanto Me ha resuelto un dilema este nuevo usuario. Por el momento, queda como mejor respuesta. Gracias! :)